# Uno Platform - how to use UserControls from a different project?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, uno-platform

I am trying to reference a user control coming from a other project into my "Shared" project in Uno Platform.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you'll need to create an "Uno Cross-Platform Library" using the Visual Studio extension, then create a user control there. There is no UI to create a `UserControl` in the 3.0 version of the templates, but this will change in Uno 3.1. You can create a `Page` and change the content to a `UserControl` instead.

Once you have created the control and built the project, you'll need to add a reference to that library to all the platform heads.

You can find a [working sample of this](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Samples/tree/master/UI/ControlLibrary) here.